# coreNLP: create a document starting from its json representation

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've run coreNLP on a large corpus and stored the annotations in JSON format by using a call to the `jsonMinified()` of a  `edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document` object.

Is there a method to create a `simple.Document` starting from a string containing the JSON representation of the document?